# C: Concatenation of 'n' strings

Tags: c

How to concatenate multiple strings in `C`?
I have a function for concatenation of two strings (no `strcat()`):

```
char* concat(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    char *r, *t;
    int d1 = -1, d2 = -1;
    while (s1[++d1]);
    while (s2[++d2]);
    t = r = (char *)calloc(d1 + d2 + 1, sizeof(char));
    while (*t++ = *s1++);
    t--;
    while (*t++ = *s2++);
    return r;
}
```

Is there a way to use this function (or `strcat()`) to concatenate multiple strings?
Also, is this dynamic allocation right:

```
char* concat(char** array, int n)
{
    char *r; int i;
    r=(char *)calloc(n*MAX+1, sizeof(char));
    array=(char **)malloc(n * sizeof(char *));
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        array[i]=(char *)malloc(MAX+1);
    }    
   ... //concatenation//...
    free(r);
    free(array[i]);
    free(array);
    return r;
}
```

Comment: `free(r)` and then `return r` .. Do you really believe it could be correct?

Comment: Where can I find the string to be consolidated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can extend the code from the first function to deal with a whole array:

```
char* concat(char** array, size_t n) {
    size_t total = 1; // One for null terminator
    for (int i = 0 ; i != n ; i++) {
        total += strlen(array[i]);
    }
    char *res = malloc(total);
    char *wr = res;
    for (int i = 0 ; i != n ; i++) {
        char *rd = array[i];
        while ((*wr++ = *rd++))
            ;
        wr--;
    }
    *wr = '\0';
    return res;
}
```

You do not need to allocate temporary 2D structures. Since you can precompute the length of the result, a single allocation is sufficient.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/sNphVU)

Comment: Note that the result is dynamically allocated and the caller is responsible to calling free()